# how to create TNS connection with SID "orcl" in apex listener

Tags: oracle, rest, oracle-apex

I almost finished to install the experimental Oracle Apex Listener. But during final installing step i got a problem: TNS name with SID with name "orcl" does not exist and it wasn't in the file "tnsnames.ora" among the others TNS names.

1. For beginning i tried to input SID characteristics for name "orcl" in the "tnsnames.ora" over notepad++ manually , but it's not helped (link to picture is below):

[ORA-12505](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydkm8.png)
2. Later i tried to input the data for SID "orcl" and open access to this over command prompt:

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\apex>sqlplus sys as sysdba
Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production


SQL> alter system set local_listener = '(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)
PORT=1521))' scope = both;

System altered.

SQL> alter system register;


System altered.

C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\apex>lsnrctl stat

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 29-JUN-2016 21:28
:13


Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                29-JUN-2016 20:37:36
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 50 min. 37 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\a
dmin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\MrPloomipuu\listen
er\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=MrPloomipuu)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=MrPloomipuu)(PORT=8025))(Presentatio
n=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

And all the same can't create SID with name 'orcl' and install TNS connecton with apex listener over that SID. What me to do here ?

Comment: It looks like you're trying this with Oracle XE. One of it's limitations is that the SID is hardcoded as XE.

Comment: Ok. Thank you, But all the same: can i create new TNS connection to my apex listener over Sql Developer ? Simply i heared what over that software i can manage all APEX Listener connection and set another one with my own SID , port , e.t.c. ))